# How to make model_builder_tf2_test.py doo the good import [PROBLEM]

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow

I'm trying to use the tensorflow api. So I create a virtual env with venv comment. I clone the github repo of tensorflow models. I download the protoc for windows version 3.20. and I build all the proto files into py files. The only things I did is to modify the import of the proto file because I couldn't build them so instead of having "object_detection/protos/ssd_anchor_generator.proto" I put "ssd_anchor_generator.proto". So everything work, all my filesare built. Then i run :

```
cp object_detection/packages/tf2/setup.py .
python -m pip install .
```

from "models/research". And I've no error. But then when I try to run the script to test the installation the module model_builder_tf2_test.py refuse to find the correct import but they are here. This is driving me crazy.
Bellow you can find the full error and a screen of my repo where we can clearly see the file.

The error :

```
(tf2_api_env) PS C:\Users\thoma\Tensorflow\models\research> python object_detection/builders/model_builder_tf2_test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\thoma\Tensorflow\models\research\object_detection\builders\model_builder_tf2_test.py", line 24, in <module>
    from object_detection.builders import model_builder
  File "C:\Users\thoma\Tensorflow\tf2_api_env\lib\site-packages\object_detection\builders\model_builder.py", line 23, in <module>
    from object_detection.builders import anchor_generator_builder
  File "C:\Users\thoma\Tensorflow\tf2_api_env\lib\site-packages\object_detection\builders\anchor_generator_builder.py", line 26, in <module>
    from object_detection.protos import anchor_generator_pb2
  File "C:\Users\thoma\Tensorflow\tf2_api_env\lib\site-packages\object_detection\protos\anchor_generator_pb2.py", line 14, in <module>
    import flexible_grid_anchor_generator_pb2 as flexible__grid__anchor__generator__pb2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flexible_grid_anchor_generator_pb2'
```

[Screen to show that flexible_grid... is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3skb.png)

And finally the content of anchor_generator_pb2.py:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Generated by the protocol buffer compiler.  DO NOT EDIT!
# source: anchor_generator.proto
"""Generated protocol buffer code."""
from google.protobuf.internal import builder as _builder
from google.protobuf import descriptor as _descriptor
from google.protobuf import descriptor_pool as _descriptor_pool
from google.protobuf import symbol_database as _symbol_database
# @@protoc_insertion_point(imports)

_sym_db = _symbol_database.Default()


import flexible_grid_anchor_generator_pb2 as flexible__grid__anchor__generator__pb2
import grid_anchor_generator_pb2 as grid__anchor__generator__pb2
import multiscale_anchor_generator_pb2 as multiscale__anchor__generator__pb2
import ssd_anchor_generator_pb2 as ssd__anchor__generator__pb2


DESCRIPTOR = _descriptor_pool.Default().AddSerializedFile(b'\n\x16\x61nchor_generator.proto\x12\x17object_detection.protos\x1a$flexible_grid_anchor_generator.proto\x1a\x1bgrid_anchor_generator.proto\x1a!multiscale_anchor_generator.proto\x1a\x1assd_anchor_generator.proto\"\x82\x03\n\x0f\x41nchorGenerator\x12M\n\x15grid_anchor_generator\x18\x01 \x01(\x0b\x32,.object_detection.protos.GridAnchorGeneratorH\x00\x12K\n\x14ssd_anchor_generator\x18\x02 \x01(\x0b\x32+.object_detection.protos.SsdAnchorGeneratorH\x00\x12Y\n\x1bmultiscale_anchor_generator\x18\x03 \x01(\x0b\x32\x32.object_detection.protos.MultiscaleAnchorGeneratorH\x00\x12^\n\x1e\x66lexible_grid_anchor_generator\x18\x04 \x01(\x0b\x32\x34.object_detection.protos.FlexibleGridAnchorGeneratorH\x00\x42\x18\n\x16\x61nchor_generator_oneof')

_builder.BuildMessageAndEnumDescriptors(DESCRIPTOR, globals())
_builder.BuildTopDescriptorsAndMessages(DESCRIPTOR, 'anchor_generator_pb2', globals())
if _descriptor._USE_C_DESCRIPTORS == False:

  DESCRIPTOR._options = None
  _ANCHORGENERATOR._serialized_start=182
  _ANCHORGENERATOR._serialized_end=568
# @@protoc_insertion_point(module_scope)
```

PS :  the import problem is not only for flexible__grid__anchor__generator__pb2 all the others import are failing...

Answer (score 1):

ok it seems i needed to modify all the import and add "from object_detection.protos" because i removed the path when building the proto files.

But seriously, I don't understand why you can't create the proto files without deleting the correct path and then you have to rewrite the correct path in each python file.

Anyways it works =)